# Centrar una div /con imagen/ en CSS

Tags: css, div

Tengo dos **divs**: **imagen_cancelando e imagen_cargando.**

**Deseo que imagen_cancelando esté en mitad de la pantalla**, centrado tanto vertical como horizontalmente, y que **imagen_cargando** esté debajo de **imagen_cancelando**, también centrado horizontalmente, con una **separación** de 5 saltos de línea respecto al primer `div`.

**¿Por qué no se centran los elementos?**

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 display: flex;
 min-height: 100vh;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
}

#imagen_cancelando{
 position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

#imagen_cancelando + #imagen_cargando{
 margin-top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Cancelando pago</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cancelando.css">
 </head>
 
 <body background="imagenes/fondo_campo4.jpg">
  <div id="imagen_cancelando">
   <img src="imagenes/cancelado.png" alt="cancelando"/>
  </div>
  
  <div id="imagen_cargando">
   <center><img src="imagenes/cargando.gif" alt="cargando" height="20px" width="20px"/></center>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Intenta meterle un margin:auto a ver si así te funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo le has dado la posición *top* y *left* a la **imagen_cancelando** y no a la **imagen_cargando**

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 display: flex;
 min-height: 100vh;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
}

#imagen_cancelando,#imagen_cargando{
 position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

#imagen_cancelando + #imagen_cargando{
 margin-top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Cancelando pago</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cancelando.css">
 </head>
 
 <body background="imagenes/fondo_campo4.jpg">
  <div id="imagen_cancelando">
   <img src="imagenes/cancelado.png" alt="cancelando"/>
  </div>
  
  <div id="imagen_cargando">
   <center><img src="imagenes/cargando.gif" alt="cargando" height="20px" width="20px"/></center>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cierto.    
El problema que tengo que al ser la imagen tan grande en "cancelando" pues se desvía más a la derecha y hacia abajo desde el punto central de la pantalla

Answer (score 2):

Si que se centran. Para el primer div quieres lo mismo que para el otro por lo que te lo modifico en el css.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 display: flex;
 min-height: 100vh;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
}

#imagen_cancelando{
 position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

#imagen_cargando{
 margin-top: 5em;
   position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Cancelando pago</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cancelando.css">
 </head>
 
 <body background="imagenes/fondo_campo4.jpg">
  <div id="imagen_cancelando">
   <img src="imagenes/cancelado.png" alt="cancelando"/>
  </div>
  
  <div id="imagen_cargando">
   <center><img src="imagenes/cargando.gif" alt="cargando" height="20px" width="20px"/></center>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: El problema que tengo que al ser la imagen tan grande en "cancelando" pues se desvía más a la derecha y hacia abajo desde el punto central de la pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

los elementos no se van a centrar porque usas "`position: absolute`", osea que estas marcando la posición.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 display: flex;
 min-height: 100vh;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
}

.marginAuto {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 800px;
}

.alin {text-align:center !important; margin-top: 5em;}



#imagen_cancelando{
 margin-top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="marginAuto">
<div class="alin">

  
  <div id="imagen_cargando">
   <center><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="cargando" height="20px" width="20px"/></center>
  </div>
  
  <div id="imagen_cancelando">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="cancelando"/>
  </div>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Mas o menos algo asi... espero te ayude...